# Can't parse API, need to convert to JSON Object - Error

Tags: json, swift, swift4

I am trying to follow this API documentation which states to pass in your API key and a json object although it keeps returning an error

It says that the contents of the request must be a JSON object and Ingredients has to be an array.

I don't know if im doing something wrong OR the API is broken. I did get another API call to work but not for the nutrients part.

```
curl -d @food.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/nutrients?app_id=${YOUR_APP_ID}&app_key=${YOUR_APP_KEY}" 

{
    "yield": 1,
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "quantity": 1,
            "measureURI": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_unit",
            "foodURI": "http://www.edaman.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Food_USDABR_45039390"
        }
    ]
}
```

In my code here is what I've gotten:

```
let json: [String: Any] = [
                           "ingredients": ["quantity":1,
                                           "measureURI":"http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_pound",
                                           "foodURI" : "http://www.edaman.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Food_USDABR_45039390"]]

let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

// Nutrition API
let app_id = "51fkkff"
let app_key = "6503a430030768824iidkos03d431d94"


let urlString = String(format: "https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/nutrients?app_id=%@&app_key=%@", app_id, app_key)
let url = URL(string: urlString)!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

request.httpBody = jsonData



let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
        return
    }
    let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
        print(responseJSON)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Error Message: `["message": Entity could not be parsed, "error": bad_request]`

Comment: You need to get past JSONSerialization. Swift 4 has JSONDecoder.

Comment: @matt I'm not decoding, i am encoding

Comment: Then JSONEncoder. Even better. Time to get over JSONSerialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I compare this to the API documentation I can see two mistakes that need to be fixed:

1. You're missing the `yield` field.
2. Ingredients should be an Array.

I just tested with this JSON object and it works fine:

```
let json: [String: Any] = [
  "yield": 1,
  "ingredients": [
    [
      "quantity": 1,
      "measureURI": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_pound",
      "foodURI": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Food_USDABR_45039390"
    ]
  ]
]
```